# create the name of a variable from the 1st index of the list and assign the list as its value

Tags: python, list

This seems to be a bit difficult to explain.
I wish to create the name of a variable from the 1st index of the list and assign the list as its value

as an example:

```
#the input is a list like below,
['name_of_variable','value1','value2','value3','value4','value5']

#the output would be as below,
name_of_variable = ['value1','value2','value3','value4','value5']
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `locals` to create a named variable this way

```
>>> data = ['name_of_variable','value1','value2','value3','value4','value5']
>>> locals()[data[0]] = data[1:]
>>> name_of_variable
['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
```

Though as a design, I would personally discourage this. If you want to map a key to value(s) I would prefer to use a `dict`

```
>>> items = {data[0]: data[1:]}
>>> items
{'name_of_variable': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']}
```

Comment: That's great . thank you @Cory Kramer